# AWS amplify TruncatingBigNumber can not be converted to an String

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

so, im trying to reset the password using the forgotPasswordSubmit from amplify, i pass as argument the security code previously asked that is sent to an email and the new password two times, when i send the values i get an error in the console:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"code":"SerializationException","name":"SerializationException","message":"class com.amazon.coral.value.json.numbers.TruncatingBigNumber can not be converted to an String"}
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41264)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
```

This is my html code:

```
<div *ngIf="newPassword">
 <form  [formGroup]="passwordForm"(ngSubmit)="verifyPassword(passwordForm.value)">
  <class="form-group">
   <label for="">Código</label>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputverifycode1"  #verifycode formControlName = "code" placeholder="Ingresa el código">
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="">Contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="exampleInputverifycode1"  #verifycode formControlName = "password" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña">
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="">Contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="exampleInputverifycode1"  #verifycode formControlName = "passwordRepeat" placeholder="vuelve a escribir tu contraseña">
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button role="button" class="btn btn-forms-submit w-100" >Aceptar</button> 
   </div>
</form>
```

And this is the code that verifies the values given through the form:

```
    passwordForm = new FormGroup({
     code: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
   password: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
     passwordRepeat: new FormControl('',[Validators.required])
   })
    verifyPassword(value){
     console.log(value);
     Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(value.code,value.password, value.passwordRepeat)
      .then(data=> console.log(data)
      )
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you've got the same id (```exampleInputverifycode1```) being used three times, might be worth making sure that's not compounding issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your number field to text for your security code (`exampleInputverifycode1` in your example). I saw the same issue when using the `verifyTotpToken` method from the `aws-amplify` with the Formik library and [this issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel/issues/104#issuecomment-276359176) pointed to a solution. If you try converting the numbers to a string further down the line from the form like I first tried, it's possible that e.g. `000123` will be interpreted as `123` causing a different type of error.  In summary, make sure your form is sending a string and not integers.